# Efeito magnético

Tags: javascript, css

Gostaria de usar este efeito num dos meus projetos.

```js
const ui = {
 btn: document.querySelector('.c-magnetic-btn')
}

const state = {
 bounds: ui.btn.getBoundingClientRect(),
 threshold: parseInt(ui.btn.dataset.threshold),
 ratio: parseInt(ui.btn.dataset.ratio),
 isMagnetic: false,
 mouse: {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
 },
 ease: {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  scale: 1,
  value: ui.btn.dataset.ease
 },
 transform: {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  scale: 1,
  max: ui.btn.dataset.max
 },
 width: window.innerWidth,
 height: window.innerHeight,
 history: false,
 scale: ui.btn.dataset.scale
}

const mouseMove = ({ pageX, pageY }) => {
 Object.assign(state, {
  mouse: {
   x: pageX,
   y: pageY
  },
  isMagnetic: isMagnetic(pageX, pageY)
 })
}

const resize = () => {
 Object.assign(state, {
  bounds: ui.btn.getBoundingClientRect(),
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
 })
}

const isMagnetic = (x, y) => {
 const { bounds } = state
 
 const centerX = bounds.left + (bounds.width / 2)
 const centerY = bounds.top + (bounds.height / 2)
 
 // use pythagorean theorem to calculate
 // cursor distance from center of btn
 // a^2 + b^2 = c^2
 const a = Math.abs(centerX - x)
 const b = Math.abs(centerY - y)
 const c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
 
 // true if cursor distance from center of btn is
 // equal to btn radius + threshold
 const isHover = c < (bounds.width / 2) + state.threshold

 if (!state.history && isHover) {
  ui.btn.classList.add('is-hover')
  Object.assign(state, {
   threshold: state.threshold * state.ratio,
   history: true
  })
 } else if (state.history && !isHover) {
  ui.btn.classList.remove('is-hover')
  Object.assign(state, {
   threshold: state.threshold / state.ratio,
   history: false
  })
 }

 return isHover
}

const run = () => {
 requestAnimationFrame(run)
 
 const { isMagnetic, transform, mouse, width, height, ease, max, scale } = state

 transform.x = isMagnetic ? (mouse.x - width / 2) / width * transform.max : 0
  transform.y = isMagnetic ? (mouse.y - height / 2) / height * transform.max : 0
 transform.scale = isMagnetic ? scale : 1
 
 // basic linear interpolation
 // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWhgniVHROw
 ease.x += (transform.x - ease.x) * ease.value
 ease.y += (transform.y - ease.y) * ease.value
 ease.scale += (transform.scale - ease.scale) * ease.value

 Object.assign(ui.btn.style, {
  transform: `
   translate(
    ${ease.x.toFixed(2)}px,
    ${ease.y.toFixed(2)}px
   )
   translateZ(0)
   scale(
    ${(ease.scale).toFixed(2)}
   )`
 })
}

const init = () => {
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove)
 window.addEventListener('resize', resize)
 run()
}

init()
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.u-fit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.u-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.u-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
.u-absolute.u-pos-tl {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.u-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.u-flex.u-center-xy {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.c-magnetic-btn {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.o-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.015);
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  will-change: opacity;
}

.t-btn-label {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 13px;
}

.is-hover .o-circle {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<button class="c-magnetic-btn u-relative" 
    data-threshold="60" 
    data-ratio="3.5"
    data-max="100"
    data-scale="1.1"
    data-ease="0.225">
 <span class="t-btn-label u-flex u-center-xy">Hover me.</span>
 <span class="o-circle u-fit u-absolute u-pos-tl"></span>
</button>
```

Não entendo praticamente nada de javascript, e o efeito em si é feito todo com javascript, precisaria de ajuda para usar esse efeito em quantos botões/elementos eu quiser, acredito que tenha como fazer isto. Acredito que seja apenas alguma alteração no javascript, poderiam me ajudar nisto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para aplicar esse efeito em qualquer elemento e sempre que quiser, tem que colocar o código responsável pelo efeito dentro de uma função `magnetic` , que recebe como parâmetro o `selector` do elemento em causa.

Exemplo:

```js
window.magnetic = function(selector) {

  const ui = {
    btn: document.querySelector('' + selector)
  }

  const state = {
    bounds: ui.btn.getBoundingClientRect(),
    threshold: parseInt(ui.btn.dataset.threshold),
    ratio: parseInt(ui.btn.dataset.ratio),
    isMagnetic: false,
    mouse: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    ease: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      scale: 1,
      value: ui.btn.dataset.ease
    },
    transform: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      scale: 1,
      max: ui.btn.dataset.max
    },
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    history: false,
    scale: ui.btn.dataset.scale
  }

  const mouseMove = ({
    pageX,
    pageY
  }) => {
    Object.assign(state, {
      mouse: {
        x: pageX,
        y: pageY
      },
      isMagnetic: isMagnetic(pageX, pageY)
    })
  }

  const resize = () => {
    Object.assign(state, {
      bounds: ui.btn.getBoundingClientRect(),
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    })
  }

  const isMagnetic = (x, y) => {
    const {
      bounds
    } = state

    const centerX = bounds.left + (bounds.width / 2)
    const centerY = bounds.top + (bounds.height / 2)

    // use pythagorean theorem to calculate
    // cursor distance from center of btn
    // a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    const a = Math.abs(centerX - x)
    const b = Math.abs(centerY - y)
    const c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)

    // true if cursor distance from center of btn is
    // equal to btn radius + threshold
    const isHover = c < (bounds.width / 2) + state.threshold

    if (!state.history && isHover) {
      ui.btn.classList.add('is-hover')
      Object.assign(state, {
        threshold: state.threshold * state.ratio,
        history: true
      })
    } else if (state.history && !isHover) {
      ui.btn.classList.remove('is-hover')
      Object.assign(state, {
        threshold: state.threshold / state.ratio,
        history: false
      })
    }

    return isHover
  }

  const run = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(run)

    const {
      isMagnetic,
      transform,
      mouse,
      width,
      height,
      ease,
      max,
      scale
    } = state

    transform.x = isMagnetic ? (mouse.x - width / 2) / width * transform.max : 0
    transform.y = isMagnetic ? (mouse.y - height / 2) / height * transform.max : 0
    transform.scale = isMagnetic ? scale : 1

    // basic linear interpolation
    // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWhgniVHROw
    ease.x += (transform.x - ease.x) * ease.value
    ease.y += (transform.y - ease.y) * ease.value
    ease.scale += (transform.scale - ease.scale) * ease.value

    Object.assign(ui.btn.style, {
      transform: `
        translate(
          ${ease.x.toFixed(2)}px,
          ${ease.y.toFixed(2)}px
        )
        translateZ(0)
        scale(
          ${(ease.scale).toFixed(2)}
        )`
    })
  }

  const init = () => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove)
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize)
    run()
  }

  init()


};

window.onload = () => {
/*
* Sempre quando quiser usar o efeito é 
* só chamar essa função e passar o selector do elemento que deseja aplicar esse efeito */
  magnetic('#c-magnetic-btn1');
  magnetic('#c-magnetic-btn2');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.u-fit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.u-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.u-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.u-absolute.u-pos-tl {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.u-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.u-flex.u-center-xy {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.c-magnetic-btn {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.o-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.015);
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  will-change: opacity;
}

.t-btn-label {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 13px;
}

.is-hover .o-circle {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<button class="c-magnetic-btn u-relative" id="c-magnetic-btn1" data-threshold="60" data-ratio="3.5" data-max="100" data-scale="1.1" data-ease="0.225">
    <span class="t-btn-label u-flex u-center-xy">Hover me.</span>
    <span class="o-circle u-fit u-absolute u-pos-tl"></span>
  </button>

<div style="width: 500px;">
</div>

<button class="c-magnetic-btn u-relative" id="c-magnetic-btn2" data-threshold="60" data-ratio="3.5" data-max="100" data-scale="1.1" data-ease="0.225">
    <span class="t-btn-label u-flex u-center-xy">Hover me.</span>
    <span class="o-circle u-fit u-absolute u-pos-tl"></span>
  </button>
```

Comment: Valeu Cristiano! Resolve meu problema!